# python selenium - getting the text of a link (a)

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

How do I get the text: "THIS TEXT"

Here is what I have tried:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('td.mainContent > a')
print(elem.text)
```

This left me really confused since I was sure that this would find the text of that a, but it didn't.  (I didn't get any error tough.. which is wierd)

the html code: (search for "THIS TEXT" to find it in the html.)

```
<tbody>


<tr class="dbaListing listing hasInsertionFee">

    <td class="pictureColumn" colspan="1">
        <div class="thumbnailContainer">
            <a class="thumbnailContainerInner" href="http://www.dba.dk/tastatur-mad-catz-strike-7/id-1029751995/">

            <img class="thumbnail lazy image-placeholder" alt="Tastatur, Mad Catz, Strike 7, Perfekt, Den er helt ny, stadig i fuld indpakning. 

Hvorfor sælger jeg?
Jeg opdagede at jeg havde skaffet det forkerte tastetur, der var ment som gave. Og siden at jeg havde ventet for længe med at få den byttet, var det altså for sent. Derfor sælger jeg den så for 1900 kr. (300 mindre en nypris)

Den er virkelig alle pengene værd, og har så mange funktioner, at jeg aldrig kan komme tæt på at beskrive alt her. Derfor hvis i er interesserede i den kan i..." data-original="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/3d/05/e060-37f5-4465-af3e-d20e730a9853.jpg?preset=srpgallery" src="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/3d/05/e060-37f5-4465-af3e-d20e730a9853.jpg?preset=srpgallery" style="display: block;">
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>

<td class="mainContent" colspan="2">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "Tastatur, Mad Catz, Strike 7, Perfekt, Den er...",
        "image": "http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/3d/05/e060-37f5-4465-af3e-d20e730a9853.jpg?preset=medium",
        "url": "http://www.dba.dk/tastatur-mad-catz-strike-7/id-1029751995/",
        "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "priceCurrency": "DKK",
            "price": "1900"
        }
    }
    </script>

    <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/tastatur-mad-catz-strike-7/id-1029751995/">
            <span class="headline-block">
                            </span>

    </a>

    <div class="expandable-box expandable-box-collapsed">
        <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/tastatur-mad-catz-strike-7/id-1029751995/">THIS TEXT</a>
        <a class="link-to-listing" href="http://www.dba.dk/tastatur-mad-catz-strike-7/id-1029751995/">Se hele annoncen</a>
    </div>


<ul class="details">

    <li>


<span>1.900 kr.</span>
    </li>

</ul>

</td>




                <td>

<span>129</span></td>
                <td>

<span>9 dage</span></td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>

        <div class="listingUpselling bump-up-upsell">
            <p>
                Er nu på side <b>57</b>.
            </p>
            <p><a href="/produkt-tilvalg/?id=1029751995&amp;produktId=BumpUp&amp;returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dba.dk%2Fmin-dbadk%2F" rel="nofollow" data-ga-act="bumpup-upsell-page-number-click" data-ga-lbl="tenzing-project" class="upsellingButton btn btn-small trackClicks">Køb oprykning</a></p>
        </div>

</td>
<td class="noWrap myDbaActions">
    <ul class="unstyled">
            <li>
                <a href="/rediger-annonce/?id=1029751995" data-ga-act="EditAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" class="trackClicks">Rediger</a>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.inactivateListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/InActivateListing', 1029751995); return false; ">Deaktiver</a>
            </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" data-ga-act="DeleteAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.deleteListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/DeleteListing', 1029751995); return false;" class="trackClicks">Slet</a>
        </li>


            <li>
                <a href="/paypal/anmodning/?externalid=1029751995" data-ga-act="click" data-ga-lbl="paypal-request-payment" class="trackClicks">Start PayPal</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/fragt/1029751995/" data-ga-act="shipping-buy-label" data-ga-lbl="shipping" class="trackClicks">Køb pakkelabel</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</td>
                </tr>  


<tr class="dbaListing listing hasInsertionFee">

    <td class="pictureColumn" colspan="1">
        <div class="thumbnailContainer">
            <a class="thumbnailContainerInner" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-akribos-xxiv-test/id-1030155633/">

            <img class="thumbnail lazy image-placeholder" alt="Dykkerur, Akribos XXIV, test" data-original="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/41/0d/7053-631b-4ba6-b520-cb0cbdd67b29.jpg?preset=srpgallery" src="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/41/0d/7053-631b-4ba6-b520-cb0cbdd67b29.jpg?preset=srpgallery" style="display: block;">
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>

<td class="mainContent" colspan="2">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "Dykkerur, Akribos XXIV, test",
        "image": "http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/41/0d/7053-631b-4ba6-b520-cb0cbdd67b29.jpg?preset=medium",
        "url": "http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-akribos-xxiv-test/id-1030155633/",
        "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "priceCurrency": "DKK",
            "price": "9999"
        }
    }
    </script>

    <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-akribos-xxiv-test/id-1030155633/">
            <span class="headline-block">
                            </span>

    </a>

    <div class="expandable-box expandable-box-collapsed">
        <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-akribos-xxiv-test/id-1030155633/">Dykkerur, Akribos XXIV, test</a>
        <a class="link-to-listing" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-akribos-xxiv-test/id-1030155633/">Se hele annoncen</a>
    </div>


<ul class="details">

    <li>


<span>9.999 kr.</span>
    </li>

</ul>

</td>




                <td>

<span>47</span></td>
                <td>

<span>29 dage</span></td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>

        <div class="listingUpselling bump-up-upsell">
            <p>
                Er nu på side <b>8</b>.
            </p>
            <p><a href="/produkt-tilvalg/?id=1030155633&amp;produktId=BumpUp&amp;returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dba.dk%2Fmin-dbadk%2F" rel="nofollow" data-ga-act="bumpup-upsell-page-number-click" data-ga-lbl="tenzing-project" class="upsellingButton btn btn-small trackClicks">Køb oprykning</a></p>
        </div>

</td>
<td class="noWrap myDbaActions">
    <ul class="unstyled">
            <li>
                <a href="/rediger-annonce/?id=1030155633" data-ga-act="EditAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" class="trackClicks">Rediger</a>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.inactivateListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/InActivateListing', 1030155633); return false; ">Deaktiver</a>
            </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" data-ga-act="DeleteAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.deleteListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/DeleteListing', 1030155633); return false;" class="trackClicks">Slet</a>
        </li>


            <li>
                <a href="/paypal/anmodning/?externalid=1030155633" data-ga-act="click" data-ga-lbl="paypal-request-payment" class="trackClicks">Start PayPal</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/fragt/1030155633/" data-ga-act="shipping-buy-label" data-ga-lbl="shipping" class="trackClicks">Køb pakkelabel</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</td>
                </tr>  


<tr class="dbaListing listing hasInsertionFee">

    <td class="pictureColumn" colspan="1">
        <div class="thumbnailContainer">
            <a class="thumbnailContainerInner" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-adidas-test/id-1030155766/">

            <img class="thumbnail lazy image-placeholder" alt="Dykkerur, Adidas, test" data-original="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/6d/45/bee3-8bb7-4e0b-9cb4-4c75ebea7ac2.jpg?preset=srpgallery" src="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/6d/45/bee3-8bb7-4e0b-9cb4-4c75ebea7ac2.jpg?preset=srpgallery" style="display: block;">
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>

<td class="mainContent" colspan="2">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "Dykkerur, Adidas, test",
        "image": "http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/6d/45/bee3-8bb7-4e0b-9cb4-4c75ebea7ac2.jpg?preset=medium",
        "url": "http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-adidas-test/id-1030155766/",
        "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "priceCurrency": "DKK",
            "price": "9999"
        }
    }
    </script>

    <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-adidas-test/id-1030155766/">
            <span class="headline-block">
                            </span>

    </a>

    <div class="expandable-box expandable-box-collapsed">
        <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-adidas-test/id-1030155766/">Dykkerur, Adidas, test</a>
        <a class="link-to-listing" href="http://www.dba.dk/dykkerur-adidas-test/id-1030155766/">Se hele annoncen</a>
    </div>


<ul class="details">

    <li>


<span>9.999 kr.</span>
    </li>

</ul>

</td>




                <td>

<span>51</span></td>
                <td>

<span>29 dage</span></td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>

        <div class="listingUpselling bump-up-upsell">
            <p>
                Er nu på side <b>8</b>.
            </p>
            <p><a href="/produkt-tilvalg/?id=1030155766&amp;produktId=BumpUp&amp;returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dba.dk%2Fmin-dbadk%2F" rel="nofollow" data-ga-act="bumpup-upsell-page-number-click" data-ga-lbl="tenzing-project" class="upsellingButton btn btn-small trackClicks">Køb oprykning</a></p>
        </div>

</td>
<td class="noWrap myDbaActions">
    <ul class="unstyled">
            <li>
                <a href="/rediger-annonce/?id=1030155766" data-ga-act="EditAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" class="trackClicks">Rediger</a>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.inactivateListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/InActivateListing', 1030155766); return false; ">Deaktiver</a>
            </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" data-ga-act="DeleteAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.deleteListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/DeleteListing', 1030155766); return false;" class="trackClicks">Slet</a>
        </li>


            <li>
                <a href="/paypal/anmodning/?externalid=1030155766" data-ga-act="click" data-ga-lbl="paypal-request-payment" class="trackClicks">Start PayPal</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/fragt/1030155766/" data-ga-act="shipping-buy-label" data-ga-lbl="shipping" class="trackClicks">Køb pakkelabel</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</td>
                </tr>  


<tr class="dbaListing listing lastListing hasInsertionFee">

    <td class="pictureColumn" colspan="1">
        <div class="thumbnailContainer">
            <a class="thumbnailContainerInner" href="http://www.dba.dk/joystick-l-h-defekt-test/id-1030156328/">

            <img class="thumbnail lazy image-placeholder" alt="Joystick, l, h, Defekt, test" data-original="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/25/48/8637-94be-42b8-a809-ed69822a40e4.jpg?preset=srpgallery" src="http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/25/48/8637-94be-42b8-a809-ed69822a40e4.jpg?preset=srpgallery" style="display: block;">
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>

<td class="mainContent" colspan="2">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "Joystick, l, h, Defekt, test",
        "image": "http://dbastatic.dk/pictures/pictures/25/48/8637-94be-42b8-a809-ed69822a40e4.jpg?preset=medium",
        "url": "http://www.dba.dk/joystick-l-h-defekt-test/id-1030156328/",
        "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "priceCurrency": "DKK",
            "price": "900"
        }
    }
    </script>

    <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/joystick-l-h-defekt-test/id-1030156328/">
            <span class="headline-block">
                            </span>

    </a>

    <div class="expandable-box expandable-box-collapsed">
        <a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/joystick-l-h-defekt-test/id-1030156328/">Joystick, l, h, Defekt, test</a>
        <a class="link-to-listing" href="http://www.dba.dk/joystick-l-h-defekt-test/id-1030156328/">Se hele annoncen</a>
    </div>


<ul class="details">

    <li>


<span>900 kr.</span>
    </li>

</ul>

</td>




                <td>

<span>44</span></td>
                <td>

<span>29 dage</span></td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>

        <div class="listingUpselling bump-up-upsell">
            <p>
                Er nu på side <b>5</b>.
            </p>
            <p><a href="/produkt-tilvalg/?id=1030156328&amp;produktId=BumpUp&amp;returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dba.dk%2Fmin-dbadk%2F" rel="nofollow" data-ga-act="bumpup-upsell-page-number-click" data-ga-lbl="tenzing-project" class="upsellingButton btn btn-small trackClicks">Køb oprykning</a></p>
        </div>

</td>
<td class="noWrap myDbaActions">
    <ul class="unstyled">
            <li>
                <a href="/rediger-annonce/?id=1030156328" data-ga-act="EditAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" class="trackClicks">Rediger</a>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.inactivateListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/InActivateListing', 1030156328); return false; ">Deaktiver</a>
            </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#" data-ga-act="DeleteAdBegin" data-ga-lbl="" onclick="Dba.MyDba.MyListings.deleteListing('/ajax/my-dba/MyDba/DeleteListing', 1030156328); return false;" class="trackClicks">Slet</a>
        </li>


            <li>
                <a href="/paypal/anmodning/?externalid=1030156328" data-ga-act="click" data-ga-lbl="paypal-request-payment" class="trackClicks">Start PayPal</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/fragt/1030156328/" data-ga-act="shipping-buy-label" data-ga-lbl="shipping" class="trackClicks">Køb pakkelabel</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</td>
                </tr>  

        </tbody>
```

Comment: What is the result of the print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you use wrong selector. Try following:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.expandable-box.expandable-box-collapsed > a.listingLink')
print(elem.text)
```

**UPDATE**

Your selector `td.mainContent > a` points to direct child of `<td class="mainContent">` and this is

```
<a class="listingLink" href="http://www.dba.dk/tastatur-mad-catz-strike-7/id-1029751995/">
        <span class="headline-block"></span>
</a>
```

As you can see, it contains no text node

Comment: It worked! You are the man, but I don't like getting the answer and not understanding it. 

Can you please explain how you came to that conclusion, and you'll get the "green solved check."

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class='mainContent']/a')
print(elem.text)
```

Comment: I didnt work, and yeah I changed 'mainContent' to "mainContent" 
Any other idea?